# rom manager needs to reflash after every reboot

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-hero, clockworkmod-recovery, rom-manager

phone : htc hero.
I've started using rom manager for clockwork mod.
However; it seems that every time I want to reboot into clockwork recovery; I need to reflash it.
Rom manager shows that current recovery is clockwork; but if try rebooting into recovery without reflashing; i get stock recovery (which ofc does not support nandroid backup :D)

Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Fake flash"](http://android.modaco.com/content/htc-desire-desire-modaco-com/312176/noob-whats-fake-flash/)

- When you boot into recovery via vol-down at power up, you get stock
- When you boot into recovery using RM you get update.zip

You need to flash permanently eg via [alpha rev](http://alpharev.nl/), [unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/) or via adb. I have a desire so what I used may not work for you.